# background image doesn't scale to fit the site

Tags: css, background, viewport

Live demo: http://leoaivy.github.io/projects/poster_inside/html/1_P.01_login.html

Questoin: ".login-bg-wrap a img" work well on desktop with max-width set to 100%. But on narrower devices like iphone 6, the background images just scale to fit the width of view port, which make their height become smaller. I set heihgt to just 1% or 100% but they scale to their original size. I don't know why? And is there a way to make the height of these images fit the height of the site?

Comment: Could you please provide some code? Show us your `css` file or the `style` tag where you define those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that every element, down to the images, is set to have a `width` of 100%. And an extra `min-width` of whatever number you want to stop the shrinking at applied to the image itself.

And only the width, not the height.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `max-width`, make the image's height and width 100%, and give it a `object-fit: cover;` Is that what you are trying to achieve?

You can also use `100vw` on the width, and `100vh` on the height, so that way the image will always have the viewport's size.